# Thread Sleeping in Xamarin Android with C#

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, timer, xamarin

I am trying to sleep my app for any milliseconds.

Developing simple app (just for fun) and I want that after my click works timer.

```
Thread.Sleep(8000);
```

Don't worked

```
new CountdownTimer(30000,1000);
```

not worked.

Is it so difficult?

Comment: Try: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21244/sleep-and-thread

Comment: @AlexandrSargsyan If I solved the issue, could you please mark as the answer, If not and you found another solution, could self answer with said solution instead. (for future viewers.)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use:

```
 await Task.Delay(x);
```

With x being milliseconds. You will evidently also need to be an an Async method for awaiting to be valid:

```
public async void Method1()
{
    //etc. 
    await Task.Delay(x);
}
```